# Finding the asymptotic behavior of a function series

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, special-functions, divergent-series, hyperbolic-functions

I solved the shape of an elastic sheet annulus clamped on the inner and outer circle with a point load (the figure below shows the cross section of an example): [Solve Green function of an annulus to calculate the shape of a clamped elastic sheet](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2834911/solve-green-function-of-an-annulus-to-calculate-the-shape-of-a-clamped-elastic-s)

I found the solution at the point load is actually divergent though any other point is convergent (just like the field of an electrical point charge).

[image]

By non-dimensionalization, now the problem to look at is a function series
$$f(r)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{\left((2r)^n-(2r)^{-n}\right)\cdot (2^n -2^{-n})}{4^n -4^{-n}}$$

Numerical tests show the terms in the series decays slower than $1/n$ for $r=1$ and thus divergent: $f(1)=\infty$ while $f(r)$ is convergent on $[\frac{1}{2},1)$.

My ideal target is to approximate the behavior near the singularity, maybe in the form $f(r)=C_1 + C_2 \cdot (1-r)^{-\alpha}$.

I'd really appreciate your kind help.

---

Follow @Delta-u 's solution, here is the plot of $\ln{(1-r)} - f(r)$:
[image]

The black solid line is $f(r)=r$.

$$g(r)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{r^n +r^{-n}}{n \cdot (4^n +1)}$$
$$g(1)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{n \cdot (4^n +1)} = 0.4715$$

$g(1)$ matches the numerical result.

Comment: It seems that rather than $f(r)=C_1 + C_2 \cdot (1-r)^{-\alpha}$ the series look like $f(r)=C_1 + C_2 \ln(1-r)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:
\begin{align}
f(r)&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{\left((2r)^n-(2r)^{-n}\right)\cdot (2^n -2^{-n})}{4^n -4^{-n}}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{(2r)^n\cdot 2^n }{4^n}+g(r)
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
g(r)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{-(2r)^{-n}\cdot (2^n -2^{-n})}{4^n -4^{-n}}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{(2r)^n\cdot (8^n -2^n-8^n+2^{-n})}{16^n -1}
\end{align}
so $g$ is well defined and continuous up to $r=1$.

As $\sum_n \frac{z^n}{n} = -\ln(1-z)$ you obtain:
$$f(r)=-\ln(1-r)+g(1)+o(1) \text{ near } r=1$$

Comment: Thanks! I have added a plot verifying your solution.